# warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char'

Tags: c, pointers

First of all, this code(PenaltyShootout.c) is used to count the number of 1's in a given string which are preceded by 2.
"0" - No goal,
"1" - Goal,
"2" - Foul.

Problem: PenatltyShootout.exe stopped working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int T,i;
    char str[100][500];
    int n=0;
```

No. of test cases are the no. of different strings to input to check the working of code.

```
    do
    {
        printf("Enter the number of Test cases(must be between 1 and 100):\n");
        scanf("%d",&T);
    }while(T>100);
```

I tried replacing str[i][500] with (char *) str[i][500] and the warning vanished, yet PenaltyShootout.exe stopped working.

```
    for(i=0; i<T; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the test case %d\n",i);
        scanf("%s",str[i][500]);
    }

    for(i=0; i<T; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<strlen(str[i])-1; j++)
        { 
            if((str[i][j]=='2')&&(str[i][j+1]=='1')==1)
            {
                n++;
            }
        }
```

This should print the number of goals made after making a foul.

```
        printf("%d\n",n);
    }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s",str[i])`

Comment: "*tried replacing `str[i][500]` with `(char *) str[i][500]` and the warning vanished, yet PenaltyShootout.exe stopped working.*" -- Never, ever, attempt to cast-away an error -- Very bad things happen...

Answer (score -1):

Your call to `scanf("%s", str[i][500]);` is reading a string (`"%s"`) into a character (`str[i][500]`).

If you are trying to read a single letter from the prompt, you need to switch it up like this:

```
scanf("%c", &str[i][500]);
```

That `"%c"` lets `scanf()` know you want a single letter, and that `&` tells it to use the address of a character in memory (`str[i][500]`, the 501th position in `str[i]` (when you only have 500 allocated)) for where to put it.

If you are trying to read a string (i.e. a word or sentence) you need to switch it up more like this:

```
scanf("%s", str[i]);
```

Here, you are now putting the scanned string into the `i`th string buffer in `str` (which you have already allocated 500 `char`s for).

Comment: You may want to mention `&str[i][500]` immediately invokes *Undefined Behavior* by attempting to write to a memory location 1-past the end of the array....